# Hide text selection handles after action in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I have several custom `UIMenuItems` that do things with a selection in a `UIWebView`.  After the action has been run on that selection I want to hide the selection handles just as `copy:` does.

I have tried using `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();` and that works in that `window.getSelection()` no longer returns anything but the text selection handles stay visible.

Is there a way to remove the selection and the handles with it?

**Edit:** I don't need it to be a **JS** solution but I can't loose the state by reloading the webview.

Comment: Matt - on my phone (and simulator), copy: doesn't hide the selection handles when it's chosen.  Does it on yours?  Please post your solution if you've found one - I'm working on this too.

Comment: Tom – hmmm, you are right...  Perhaps this is something that is not possible.  What I am doing is getting the selection and surrounding it with a new div.  What I don't like is that the blue selection handles then show up at the old position of the selected text like an I with two blue dots.  The related problem is that if I programmatically change the selection I don't believe the blue text selection box adjusts to that new range.

Comment: That's the same behavior I've experienced.  It seems there's no way to change the selection range from javascript.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just disable and re-enable the User Interaction:

```
myWebView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
myWebView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Brilliant!  You earned it!  You know you have the right solution when it is so simple...:)

Comment: Thanks. I love simple solutions to apparently difficult problems :)

Comment: @Sylter - thanks. If only this answer was easier to find on google!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me on iOS 5, anyone still able to get this to work?

Comment: its doesnt work bcz if contain is large or we userInterfacetionEnable=NO then we cannot able to scroll Webview

Comment: For me, this is working well on an iPhone 5 running iOS 8.1.3, but doesn't work in the same app running under iOS 9.0.2 on an iPhone 6.  Under iOS 9 the Edit menu goes away, but text selection stays.  If I "slow it down" it works - ie first set to NO, wait, then set to YES.  So it feels a bit brittle.  From my research, the fact that window.getSelection().removeAllRanges() doesn't work is a bug in iOS.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply refresh the webview if your data is only text then no body can trace that webview is refreshed

use this code

```
[webview reload];
```

i have done this thing in my apps & its work great

Comment: I can't reload the whole webview as that would change state that is in the webview.  I just need to get those handles to disappear. ;)

Answer (score -2):

`[_webview becomeFirstResponder];` After your action.

You just need this. I always use this way.