# Programmatically remove selection in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiwebview

Is there a way to programmatically remove the selection box of text which the user has selection in a UIWebView?

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542347/hide-text-selection-handles-after-action-in-uiwebview ...

Answer (score 4):

Just disable and re-enable the User Interaction:

*myWebView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
myWebView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;*

Try this,

Comment: It totally brakes user input.

Answer (score 2):

For `WKWebView`:

```
wkWebView.scrollView.subviews.first?.resignFirstResponder()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * jsCallBack = @"window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();";    
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
```

Comment: Didn't work - I want to remove the selection with the two handles which appears in the view, but it remains...

Comment: when you select text on the ipad/iphone you have the selection box with the two circles you may drag to resize it - I want to be able to remove this selection

Comment: @Sam Soffes so let me get this straight, you are running around SO down voting answers? LOL

Comment: If the answer doesn't solve the question, I will down vote it, yes.

Comment: It stops user input! How to fix it?

Answer (score -2):

Sure... using JavaScript in the HTML document the UIWebView is displaying.

I suspect that's not what you mean by "programmatically", though...

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.